# How do you import a Maven dependency from Sonatype.org?

Tags: maven, robolectric, sonatype

I'm trying to import [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) into my Maven project, with:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pivotallabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
            <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The artifact is listed here:

https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~robolectric

I tried including:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>oss-sonatype</id>
        <name>oss-sonatype</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

as suggested from [this post](http://mytechaddiction.blogspot.com/2012/07/intellij-robolectric-and-android.html?showComment=1355892044761), but it doesn't resolve robolectric.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work although you should really install a repository manager like Sonatype Nexus and proxy the oss snapshot repository.

In your case the problem might be that it did not find it previously and that fact is cached in your local repository. To force Maven to check agagin use the -U flag so e.g. run

```
mvn -U clean install
```

Comment: Because that way you get the benefit of performance and stability from it being in your local network ideally. In addition you can deploy third party libraries (like the android.jar and others) into the repo manager and deploy your own libraries into it as well to share them across your team. And e.g. QA can pick up the apk from it for their testing and later for deployment.

Comment: I set up Nexus for my team over a month ago. Such a lifesaver. We have a ton of third party jars (proprietary), and deploying them to Nexus saved us a ton of headache. Highly recommend.